# How to use PreparedAsync In ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have an application that uses ExoPlayer. But it's done so before the start, I need to know Prepared is already ready or not.

I can not find PreparedAsync in ExoPlayer. Therefore, the application crashes

Running and training is 2 different things.

I need to find out when the preparation is over, To get the length of the video track.

---

I need any suggestions. Already 4 days I rack my brains. Help Developers ((

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the following code :

```
// Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
// Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, "com.yourapp.appname"), bandwidthMeter);
// Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
// This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
        MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(uri,
                dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
// Prepare the player with the source.
        exoPlayer.prepare(videoSource);
```

Comment: А как использовать prepare Async?| In Media Player, there is prepareAsync. And here there is no

Answer (score 0):

You should add a listener. Its onPlayerStateChanged will be invoked when a state change occurs.

Note that if all you're trying to do is start playback as soon as possible, there's no need for you to wait until preparation happens for you to tell the player that you want it to start playback. Just call `setPlayWhenReady(true)` straight away, and it'll start playing as soon as possible.

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ExoPlayer exoPlayer;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private int RENDERER_COUNT = 300000;
    private int minBufferMs =    250000;
    private final int BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE = 64 * 1024;
    private final int BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT = 256;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        surfaceView= (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0";
        String url = "http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/480/big_buck_bunny_480p_5mb.mp4";
        Allocator allocator = new DefaultAllocator(minBufferMs);
        DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(this, null, userAgent);


        ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource( Uri.parse(url), dataSource, allocator,
                BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT * BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);

        MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer videoRenderer = new
                MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(this, sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT,
                MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT);

        MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT);

        exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(RENDERER_COUNT);
        exoPlayer.prepare(videoRenderer, audioRenderer);
        exoPlayer.sendMessage(videoRenderer,
                MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_SURFACE,
                surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    }
}
```

BY: **Jens Klingenberg**